# SharePoint 2010 - is it possible to populate a dataform web part with REST?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a custom page in SharePoint 2010 that is using a DataFormWebPart to display data from a very large list (almost 5000 items). I have a query defined in XSL in the DataFormWebPart that is querying data from the list. When I increase the size of the list to over 5000 items, I get an error saying that I'm exceeding the list view threshold.

I'm using a simple CAML query to filter the data from the list. My query should never return even close to 5000 items. I've got indexing turned on for the columns that I'm filtering on in the query. I'm not sure what else to try at this point, except to possibly try a different data source.

Is it possible to replace the SPDataSource call to the list with a REST call?

edit: Here's the CAML query

```
<Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Location' /><Value Type='Lookup'>{$Location}</Value></Contains></Where></Query>
```

Comment: Could you show us your CAML query? It's possible that the way it's designed is causing it to bump up against the list view threshold even if it would return fewer than 5000 items.

Comment: Please see above. I edited the question and added the CAML query that I'm using. I have also tried it with a second lookup value within the <contains> tags, so that it would filter on both values, but that had the same results.

Comment: Ah, that's the problem. Queries that use the "contains" condition can't take advantage of indexing to circumvent the list view threshold. This makes sense if you think about it... indexing a column is equivalent to putting books in alphabetical order on a shelf. It makes it easier to find a particular title because you can pinpoint the correct spot for it without checking every title in sequence. But a "contains" query is like trying to find every book on a shelf that has the word "dog" somewhere in its title; the books being in alphabetical order won't help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that means switching to REST wouldn't help you... you'll still be restricted by the list view threshold. Would you be able to use `<BeginsWith>` instead of `<Contains>`?

Comment: <BeginsWith> unfortunately results in the same error message when the list is over 5000 items. I also tried <Eq> and got the same results. Any other query tags that you're aware of that I could try that might work with the indexing? Thanks for the help by the way. I'm fairly new to this and trying to fix an older project written by someone else.

Comment: Well, it the `<Eq>` query doesn't work then that tells us that there's definitely something wrong with the column indexing.

Comment: Double check whether the Location column is indexed. You might also want to index the column that it points to (that is, in the foreign list).

Comment: Ok I checked and the Location column is indexed. I also added an index on the column that it looks up in the foreign list (good call btw). Still getting the same results though. I'm still using <BeginsWith> at this point. Should I switch to <Eq>?

Comment: Also, would adding another condition help? I have another column that's indexed (Region, also a lookup) that I could filter on as well if it would help.

Comment: Yeah, I'd see if you can get `<Eq>` to work with an exact match before trying to get `<BeginsWith>` to work, just to take it one problem at a time. I'd hold off adding more filter conditions while you troubleshoot this one.

Comment: I'm doing some testing now to confirm... Might be a problem inherent to Lookup columns.

Comment: Ok thanks. Changing to <Eq> resulted in the same error message on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here's what I've discovered.

Filtering against the **text value** of a lookup column does **not** work in a CAML query vs a list that has surpassed the list view threshold.

It appears that indexing a lookup column only indexes the **lookup IDs** of the column values, not the lookup values themselves.

You can, however, filter against the lookup ID of the lookup column in your CAML query.

#### Example: Filtering on Timbuku

For example, let's say you want to query for any items with their `Location` lookup column set to "Timbuktu".

You might use this query:

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name=\"Location\" />
        <Value Type=\"Lookup\">Timbuktu</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
```

That query will work up until the list reaches the list view threshold of 5000, at which point it will fail, **even if the `Location` column is indexed**.

To work around this, you can find Timbuktu's corresponding item in the foreign list and determine its ID. Let's say it's 42. You can then use the ID number in the query like so:

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name=\"Location\" LookupId=\"true\" />
        <Value Type=\"Lookup\">42</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
```

Note the addition of the `LookupId=\"true\"` in the `FieldRef` element.

That will work even after the list view threshold is surpassed.

#### What this means for you

Overall, it's not good news for your web part.

You would need to first query the locations lookup list for any items corresponding to the desired value, then use the IDs of those items to filter your actual data.

This actually isn't too tough to do programmatically, either with REST or the JavaScript Object Model, but it means you'll likely need to scrap the existing XSLT web part.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I may be able to mod it to use the ID number in it's current state. I may try that first. We're doing an upgrade to 2013 sometime within the next month or two, and I'd rather wait til that's done before rewriting the whole thing in JavaScript. Thanks for all your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: How do you find the lookup ID? Is there a hidden column that's created when a lookup column is created? Is the lookup ID the same as the ID of the list that's being looked up (the foreign list)?

Comment: @Jason It's the same as the ID field's value on the item that's being looked up from the foreign list. If you want, you can edit the lookup column and in "additional column settings" click the checkbox next to "ID" to pull in the lookup ID from the lookup list.